# Java xml parsing- locating a specific result:

Tags: java, api, parsing, sax

So I've been playing around with Sax the past few days and I've been completely unable to handle this issue I've run into.

Assume that I have the following xml

```
<PowerSystemRegions>
<PowerSystemRegion>
    <RegionId>1</RegionId>
    <RegionName>New England</RegionName>
    <Status>Normal</Status>
    <DateUpdated>2011-12-22T10:55:51.000-05:00</DateUpdated>
</PowerSystemRegion>
<PowerSystemRegion>
```

And I wanted to first check to make sure that the region name is New England, and then pull the status based off of that, but I don't think it would load the next qName or anything since it would call again from main.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm utterly stuck:

```
public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    boolean region = false;
    boolean regionName = false;
    boolean regionStatus = false;

    if (qName.compareTo("RegionName") == 0) {
        region = true;
        if(atts.getValue(0).compareTo("New England") == 0){

        }

        if (currentStatus == null){
        String cCond = atts.getValue(0);
        currentStatus = cCond;
        }   
    }
}
```

It was my idea to compare the names and once all 3 booleans were set I'd be fine... but then it struck me that it wouldn't work that way due to only having one qName in the string... Halp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with sax, but I'll try:
You could add in your handler fields like:

```
public class SaxHandler {
    Integer regionId;
    String regionName;
    String regionStatus;

    (...)
}
```

So, in your start element, you make something like:

```
public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    if (qname.equals("RegionName") {
        regionName = atts.getValue(0);
    }
    if (qname.equals("RegionId") {
        regionId = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue(0));
    }
    if (qname.equals ("Status") {
        if(regionName.equals ("New England")) {
            //Do what you want here
        }

    }

}
```

By the way, its better use equals instead of compareTo. Use compareTo only if you're sorting elements ;)

**EDIT:** Thinking in objects, better use classes, instead of fields like I did. Use a PowerSystem object to collect the data from the xml ;)